# SQL query for the total number of employees for the selected period in the SCD2 table

Tags: sql, t-sql, scd2

I would need a help for the sql syntax which would give me the total number of employees for the selected period in the SCD2 table. Examples are provided below - the thing is that i get the inconsistent results for the totals, i guess due to the fact that i'm using "FlagIsCurrent" variable. Since the variable "ValidFrom" and "ValidTo" refer to the period when somebody worked in the specific store or quit, would it be possible to get the consistent results with those variables? "FlagIsCurrent" only refers to the current state of affairs and i want to go "into past".

Any ideas?

Table looks similar like this:

| EmployeeID | StoreID | EmploymentDate | TerminationDate | ValidFrom | ValidTo | FlagIsCurrent | LoadDateTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| e01 | 5 | 2010-10-01 | 1900-01-01 | 2010-10-01 | 9999-12-31 | 1 | 2023-01-05 23:00:27.543 |
| e02 | 4 | 2022-10-10 | 1900-01-01 | 2022-10-10 | 2022-12-10 | 0 | 2023-01-01 23:00:27.543 |
| e02 | 5 | 2022-10-10 | 1900-01-01 | 2022-12-13 | 9999-12-31 | 1 | 2023-01-05 23:00:27.543 |
| e03 | 3 | 2023-02-20 | 1900-01-01 | 2023-02-20 | 9999-12-31 | 1 | 2023-01-05 23:00:27.543 |
| e04 | 3 | 2022-08-25 | 1900-01-01 | 2022-08-25 | 2022-12-04 | 0 | 2023-01-01 23:00:27.543 |
| e04 | 3 | 2022-08-25 | 2022-12-05 | 2022-12-05 | 9999-12-31 | 1 | 2023-01-05 23:00:27.543 |

**Hires for the selected period (works ok):**

```
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT [EmployeeID])
FROM [import].[hr].[Employees]
WHERE [EmploymentDate]>=MIN(Calendar[Date]) AND [EmploymentDate]<=MAX(Calendar[Date])

...or for the specific month:

SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT [EmployeeID])
FROM [import].[hr].[Employees]
WHERE [EmploymentDate]>='2023-02-01' AND [EmploymentDate]<='2023-02-28'
```

**Terminations for the selected period (works ok):**

```
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT [EmployeeID])
FROM [import].[hr].[Employees]
WHERE [TerminationDate]<>'1900-01-01' AND [TerminationDate]>=MIN(Calendar[Date]) AND [TerminationDate]<=MAX(Calendar[Date])

...or for the specific month:

SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT [EmployeeID])
FROM [import].[hr].[Employees]
WHERE [TerminationDate]<>'1900-01-01' AND [TerminationDate]>='2023-02-01' AND [TerminationDate]<='2023-02-28'
```

**Totals for the selected period (inconsistent results):**

```
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT [EmployeeID])
FROM [import].[hr].[Employees]
WHERE [FlagIsCurrent]='1'
AND
(
([TerminationDate]='1900-01-01' AND [EmploymentDate]<=MAX(Calendar[Date])
OR
([EmploymentDate]<=MAX(Calendar[Date]) AND [TerminationDate]>=MIN(Calendar[Date])
))

...or for the specific month:

SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT [EmployeeID])
FROM [import].[hr].[Employees]
WHERE [FlagIsCurrent]='1'
AND
(
([TerminationDate]='1900-01-01' AND [EmploymentDate]<='2023-02-28'
OR
([EmploymentDate]<='2023-02-28') AND [TerminationDate]>='2023-02-01'
))
```

**UPDATE**

Is it safe to assume that the total number of employees for the selected period would be the following:

```
SELECT COUNT ([EmployeeID]) FROM [import].[hr].[Employees] WHERE [TerminationDate] IS '1900-01-01' AND [ValidFrom]<=MAX(Calendar[Date]) AND [ValidTo]>=MIN(Calendar[Date])

...or for the last February that would be:

SELECT COUNT ([EmployeeID]) FROM [import].[hr].[Employees] WHERE [TerminationDate] IS '1900-01-01' AND [ValidFrom]<='2023-02-28' AND [ValidTo]>='2023-02-01'
```

Comment: Have a look at the [`overlap`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/overlap/info) tag description. It explains how to test for overlapping ranges. A more complete example would help us help you. You mention the `SCD2` table, but didn't include it. Nor DDL for the tables. Nor expected results.

Comment: The purpose of an SCD2 table is to hold the state of a record at a point in time, so when you want to query such a table the first thing you need to decide is what point in time you want to use for your query. This might be the current state, in which case you just filter on FlagIsCurrent=1, or if you want to filter for a specific date you select where that date is between ValidFrom and ValidTo. What you shouldn’t be doing is trying to handle the fact that there are multiple records for each EmployeeID by using DISTINCT

Comment: In any case , condition `` [FlagIsCurrent]='1'`` is seems superfluous.

Comment: Hi guys, sorry for the late reply.

Is it safe to assume that the total number of employees for the selected period would be the following:

SELECT
COUNT ([EmployeeID])
FROM [import].[hr].[Employees]
WHERE [TerminationDate] IS '1900-01-01' AND [ValidFrom]<=MAX(Calendar[Date]) AND [ValidTo]>=MIN(Calendar[Date])



...or for the last February that would be:

SELECT
COUNT ([EmployeeID])
FROM [import].[hr].[Employees]
WHERE [TerminationDate] IS '1900-01-01' AND [ValidFrom]<='2023-02-28' AND [ValidTo]>='2023-02-01'

Comment: Hi - please update your question rather than adding additional information in comments. For one thing, it will allow you to format your SQL so it is readable. Thanks

Comment: Hi @NickW, i just did - sorry. Can you take a look?